# Load multiple versions of the same GAE endpoint?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The endpoints in our project have progressed, necessitating a bump in version number. Let's call it `appService`. Formerly we were loading the APIs for use in JS using the following:

`gapi.client.load('appService', 'v1')`

The endpoints would then be available on the `gapi.client.appService` object:

`gapi.client.appService.collectionOfEndpoints.doStuff()`

This is problematic because it's not accessed by version number. That means that loading `v2` of the endpoints (`gapi.client.load('appService', 'v2')`) will overwrite any `v1` endpoint accessors in the object.

Is it possible to have both `v1` and `v2` of the same API loaded and available for consumption using the JavaScript generated endpoints?

Comment: Why do you need two versions of an API to be loaded? If you need functionality in v1 then it should also be in v2.

Comment: Not that I know the answer to the question. But the `gapi.client.Request` method should be able to help you. I have not used it. but since the urls themselves will include v1 or v2, you can decide that way. Of this might mean rewriting your calls. But so far, it's my best guest.